# wp_list_comments() orderby meta_key

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to order comments by a `meta_key` on `wp_list_comments` array - just like a regular Wordpress post query?

```
<?php
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'style'       => 'ul',
        'short_ping'  => true,
        'avatar_size' => 60,
        'callback'  =>  'user_comment'
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `get_comments`. In the `$args` you pass it, you can set all of the usual orderby parameters. Unlike `wp_list_comments`, it returns an object with comment info, so you'll have to handle the output yourself . Take a look at the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments), it covers it all pretty well.